# how to upload csv/xlsx file to mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, mongoose, xlsx

I am developing an app with nodeJS, express and a mongoDB, I need to take users' data from a csv file and upload it to my database this db has a schema designed with mongoose.

But I don't know how to do that. What is the best approach to read the csv/xlsx file and check for duplicates against the db and, if the user (one column in the csv) is not there, insert him?

Is there any module to do this? or do I need to build it from scratch? I'm pretty new to nodeJS and I need some advice here.

This app has an angular front-end so the user can upload the file, maybe I should read the csv/xlsx in the front end and transform it into an array for node, then insert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `csv` file you can use node module 'csv-parse'.

1. read the csv file using node 'fs' module
2. pass the data to csv parser and you will get arry of array, where inner array represents each row.

Take a look at the following code.

```js
var csvParser = require('csv-parse');

fs.readFile(filePath, {
            encoding: 'utf-8'
        }, function(err, csvData) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
  
            csvParser(csvData, {
                delimiter: ',' 
            }, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

Here filePath is path of the csv file and the delimiter will be as per your file. It is the character that separates fields in csv file(can be ',', '.', etc).

Then you can use `findOneAndUpdate` query for mongodb. You can also use other approach.

```
userModel
        .findOneAndUpdate({
            user: userObject.user
        }, {
            $set: userObject
        }, {
            upsert: true,
            multi: false
        })
        .exec(function(err, user) {
            console.log(err,user);
        });
```

Comment: thanks.... but the files can be either csv or xlsx so is there any way to store both types of files using a similar way......

Comment: @ishakya I think you can convert the `xlsx` file to `csv` then you can use this and please do a search to find better solution.

Comment: I used csv-parser as u suggested and for xlsx file i used excel module then manually converted it into json data to store it in db.....

Comment: @Asis Datta: Do you have any sample of this project?